# Weblogic Workshop asks to upgrade projects everytime

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using the Weblogic Workshop for Portlet development.  It's built on Eclipse.  I upgraded my Eclipse from 3.2 to Weblogic Workshop. 
The problem is that everytime I start the Workshop it gives me an upgrade information that I need to upgrade my projects as they were created with older version of Eclipse.
This should have to be done only once, right?  Not everytime.  Is there a solution?

Text of message:

"Upgrade projects created with older release of Eclipse and/or related plugins."

Thanks,

Sid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your project in a source control system that may have made some files read-only? If so, use your source control client to "check out" all project files before opening the project in Eclipse. Then find files that have been changed by upgrade and check them back in.

If that doesn't apply to your situation, take a look at your Error Log view in Eclipse after upgrade. Are there any errors/exceptions in there? You may want to clear the log and repeat to get only the most recent problems. Use information that you gather to open a support ticket at Oracle. The problem that you are describing is likely a bug.